# Defining variables in django template

Tags: django, loops, templates, for-loop

I have a dictionary and a list. The dictionary contains the title and link of an youtube video and list contains the description. I want to print the respective tile and description.

```
{% for key,values in link.items%}
    <a><h4>{{key}}</h4></a>
    <p><b>Description:</b> {{description[how do i iterate the description]}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

I tried to create a variable `{{i}}` and increment it, but it didn't work.

Views.

```
def search(request):
    from . import search_yt 
    #list for thumbnail src
    thumb = []
    #link is dict and description is list
    link,description = search_yt.search_youtube(request.POST['query'])

    #Preparing the thumbnail src
    for key,value in link.items():
        key = key
        thumb.append("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+value[32:]+"/hqdefault.jpg")

    context = {
        'query' : request.POST['query'],
        'link' : link,
        'description' : description,
        'thumbnail' : thumb
    }
    return render(request,'index/search.html',context)
```

Comment: But a dictionary is unordered, so that will not work in the first place. Furthermore you need to do the processing in the *view*. The template should only contain *render* logic, not that much *what is rendered* (and how it is linked).

Comment: Can you show the view that will render this template? It looks to me that there is something conceptually wrong with it.

Comment: I have attached the views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have changed all of that into the list and now I have a problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578209/iterating-lists-in-django-template