# Iterating lists in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have different lists

```
context = {
    'query' : request.POST['query'],
    'link' : link,
    'description' : description,
    'title' : title,
    'thumbnail' : thumb,
    'range' : range(len(title)),
}
```

And I want to iterate through them something like:

```
for i in range(20):
    link[i]
    title[i]
```

In django template. How can i do it?

Comment: What are `link` and `title` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't typically you use a `zip` construct in the view, and then iterate concurrently over both (or more) iterators:

```
context = {
    'query' : request.POST['query'],
    'linktitle' : zip(link, title),
    'description' : description,
    'thumbnail' : thumb,
    'range' : range(len(title)),
}
```

and then in the template:

```
{% for linki, titlei in linktitle %}
   {{ linki }} / {{ titlei }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are only interested in the first 20 elements, you can add a `range(20)` in the zip, or use `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

context = {
    'query' : request.POST['query'],
    'linktitle' : islice(zip(link, title), 20),
    'description' : description,
    'thumbnail' : thumb,
    'range' : range(len(title)),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably better off creating those link-title pairs in your view where you have the full Python arsenal (e.g. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip)) at your disposal:

```
context = {
    'link' : link,
    'title' : title,
    'link_title': list(zip(link, title)),
    # ...
}
```

You can slice that convenience list in the template if necessary:

```
{% for l, t in link_title|slice:":20" %}
    # do stuff with l, t
{% endfor %}
```